# Appium: Should not start App or Activity on startup / Testing unlock passcodes

Tags: android, testing, appium, device

I have to test some Android devices for there security policies.
So when an update or the policies comes out for one of the secured apps we can run our test to ensure the update/policies are not going to open new security issues.

We decided to use Appium to automate our test cases.

I'm stucking now on running the launcher app.
I preferred not to open an App on startup, because there is no app that should be tested. But Appium reqiered an declared activity and package.
I decided to specify the launcher app as entry point, that's working fine but, if the device is locked, appium cannot launch the launcher app and it is stucking.

I tried to use "unlockType" and "unlockKey" to unlock the device, this is also working, it unlocks the device once at the beginning but i have to test several unlocking scenarios (e.g. device wipe after entering 10 wrong passcodes).

Does some one have a idea how to test this scenario properly?
Or is Appium generally not usable to test whole devices?

Thank you for your ideas and opinions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably figured this out by now, but what you were looking might be the DesiredCapability "autoLaunch". Set it to false, then the driver won't open the app until you tell it to do so by

```
driver.launchApp();
```

Just posting this for anybody with the same problem, took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: be aware that autolaunch capability also disable app installation during Appium session initialization.. A bit misleading name.